# htaccess https redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I'm moving a site to cloud hosting that provides SSL but at a subdomain. My question is can a secure page (with no certificate - so it displays untrusted) be redirected to the right place?

https://www.domain.com to https://web242.secure-secure.co.uk/domain.com

This is what I've attempted (placed in the root) so far but it doesn't do anything:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web242.secure-secure.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://web242.secure-secure.co.uk/domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It doesn't work with this in either (although I'm not sure where to try it):
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} on

Thanks

Comment: The answer is no it can't. You can't redirect a site that is showing untrusted without a valid cert. SSL handshake happens before any modrewrite/redirect so you can't use rewrite for that.  You might be able to do domain forwarding with DNS, but haven't tested that.

Comment: Thanks anyway @panama jack